# jQuery change() Method NOT working on input value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to get the total value for the `#OrderTotalValue` using jQuery `change()` Method. When I enter number on the input, it should automatically calculate the sum and update on the `#OrderTotalValue`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input").on('change', function() {
    var calculatedTotalSum = 0;

    $("#EditTotals .col-md-9").each(function() {
      var getPriceValue = $(this).val();
      if ($.isNumeric(getPriceValue)) {
        calculatedTotalSum += parseFloat(getPriceValue);
      }
    });
    $("#OrderTotalValue").html(calculatedTotalSum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="EditTotals">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label asp-for="TaxRatesValue" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <editor asp-for="TaxRatesValue" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label asp-for="TaxValue" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <editor asp-for="TaxValue" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label asp-for="OrderTotalDiscountValue" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <editor asp-for="OrderTotalDiscountValue" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label asp-for="OrderTotalValue" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <editor asp-for="OrderTotalValue">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried different codes like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#EditTotals").change(function() {
    var calculatedTotalSum = 0;
    $(":input").each(function() {
      calculatedTotalSum = calculatedTotalSum + parseInt($(this).val());
    })
    $("#OrderTotalValue").val(calculatedTotalSum);
  });
});
```

Comment: Use `.on("input"` instead - but you do not HAVE an input

Comment: Also please post HTML and not ASP

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a class to `TaxRatesValue`,`TaxValue`,`OrderTotalDiscountValue`,or it will also calculate  the value of `OrderTotalValue`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="EditTotals">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label asp-for="TaxRatesValue" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <editor class="calculate" asp-for="TaxRatesValue" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label asp-for="TaxValue" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <editor class="calculate" asp-for="TaxValue" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label asp-for="OrderTotalDiscountValue" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <editor class="calculate" asp-for="OrderTotalDiscountValue" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label asp-for="OrderTotalValue" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <editor asp-for="OrderTotalValue">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input").on('change', function() {
    var calculatedTotalSum = 0;

    $(".calculate").each(function() {
      var getPriceValue = $(this).val();
      if ($.isNumeric(getPriceValue)) {
        calculatedTotalSum += parseFloat(getPriceValue);
      }
    });
    $("#OrderTotalValue").html(calculatedTotalSum);
  });
});
```